# Do twice more atoms absorb twice more photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, particle-detectors

Let's assume you have a photon detector that detect individual photons striking it when exposed to a weak light source.

Now let's assume you somehow managed to make a denser detector from the same material (eg. by crystallizing it differently). Now you have more atoms at the same area. More atoms that could potentially get excited by light. Would the new detector detect more photons when exposed to the same light source?

Comment: Depends on the absorption length in the material, does it not? If the original detector can already absorb all the light because it's much thicker than the absorption length, then adding more material does nothing. That's usually meant by an optically "thick" detector. If, on the other hand, the detector is optically "thin", then one can increase detection efficiency by adding more thickness. This, by the way, also goes for concentrations of absorbing centers.

Comment: @CuriousOne  I agree. Sounds like you have an answer.

Comment: @Calmarius: no, the problem is not that simple. There are additional parameters to be considered, e.g. the lifetime of the atom unstable level that absorbs the photon. To be able to serve for detection, the level has to be a sort of convertor, absorb the photon and then, undergo de-excitation, for being able to absorb another photon. If the life-time of the excited level is not enough short, given the intensity of the photon flux, then definitely additional atoms in the same volume, are of help. But I don't know if the relation is linear, twice more atom twice bigger the efficiency.